# Lodash file not found but it's listed correctly in index.html and is in the described directory

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Has anyone has this problem? Is there a conflict between Underscore and Lodash? In the past it seems like Underscore supersedes Lodash so I commented out the Underscore which in this case removed Underscore but has not allowed me access to my lodash 3.2 update.

My index.html:

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
<!--<script src="../bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>-->
<script src="../node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
```

I had lodash and underscore in both bower_components and node_modules. I took out underscore from node_modules. I just want to get lodash working, I need a couple of the functions.

Comment: Remove the reference to the earlier version of lodash. There would be a conflict between lodash and underscore since they both use the same _ namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to mind here.

First, both Underscore and Lodash will define the same **global variable**, `_`.

Therefore, if you add both, the last one declared will "win". This happens simply because the browser evaluates the declared `script` tags in the order they appear.

This is unnecessary as it forces the browser to download extra bytes for nothing. So **choose one and delete the others**.

This **also** applies to multiple versions of the same library. So, in your case, the last declared version of `lodash` will win.

Second, you seem to reference `lodash` directly from `node_modules`. You should keep in mind that dependencies from `node_modules` are not *usually* imported directly into your HTML. The most common way to go about is to use a tool like [WebPack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/what-is-webpack.html), which lets you combine multiple dependencies into one file.

The reason for that is that `node_modules` dependencies may become unpredictably nested. `bower_components`, on the other hand, keeps all dependencies on the root folder and makes you choose when there are conflicts. This more closely resembles the environment of a browser. You can read more about this here: http://blog.npmjs.org/post/101775448305/npm-and-front-end-packaging

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. This will come in handy in the future!